# Check Email sent Successfully or not to the users

Tags: c#, .net

i can't able to get the response from the user sides email sent or not

How to handle the response status our database the email sent successfully or not to the user using smtp email sending in C# .Net core web api anyone can give me some ideas how we can resolve this issues                                                        ?

Comment: It is not clear from your question, but if you want to know if the email has been delivered to the recipient then there is no official supported way to know this See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095104/how-to-confirm-that-mail-has-been-delivered-or-not

Comment: Instead if you live in a country that has a [Certified Email system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_email#References) then it is another game and you can have some chance to programmatically check the delivery of the mail to the recipient.

Comment: If i given wrong mail id and also not registered mail id i sent mail both scenario how to check mail was sent or not from user

Comment: _"If i given wrong mail id and also not registered mail id i sent mail both scenario how to check mail was sent or not from user"_ doesn't make sense to me. You sent the mail, didn't you? What you want is to confirm reception, right? Well, that's not designed into email. You can somehow confirm that your SMTP Server (i.e. the one you are using) has _sent_ the email, but you cannot (really and _in general_) confirm, that the receiving email server got it, accepted it (some may send rejection notices, though) _and_ delivered it to the appropriate user.

Comment: What you _can_ do is include a confirmation link or code that the user has to follow or enter to complete a registration process, for example.