# What are the common things that cause an email not to get forwarded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have proper setting for `smtp` in `web.config`, and it runs without error, but the email don't get forwarded to appropriate user what may be the reason behind this, am i missing some server setting, please light on it.

While i see it get saved in `specifiedPickupDirectory`.

Comment: Is it an external email address, or one within your network?

Comment: there many thinks that you can check and all depend from the mail server and the limits that exist on the mail server. What error did you get ?

Comment: @Aristos : OP mentioned that **"and it runs without error"**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Is just not find or track the errors, this is not mean that is not exist. And if there are no errors the next think is the trace. From the moment that is not forwarded then somewhere an error exist. Not error in code, but what about error from mail server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no practical way of tracking an email, whether it delivered or not after it sends from your server unless you get undeliverable email from client.

But still your email can be delivered as a spam on client or may be reject from client server.

Anyway you can handle exception from your side to make a good chance for deliver the email.

You can try using `System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess` wwhcih can be found in [DeliveryNotificationOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx)

Also there is similar kind of question can be found [How to check MailMessage was delivered in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973725/how-to-check-mailmessage-was-delivered-in-net)